# Create PLSQL code to print grades of 10 students

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

'Below is program for PLSQL to print grades of students. Program executes successfully but unable to print grades. Any suggestions/corrections?

STEP:1

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
  ROLL_NO   NUMBER,
  NAME      VARCHAR2(100),
  SECTION   NUMBER,
  CLASS     VARCHAR2(100),
  ORACLE    NUMBER,
  Dev_2000  NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (1, 'AVINASH', 9025, 'STUDENT', 75, 85)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (2, 'AKASH', 9025, 'WORKING', 45, 85);
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (3, 'ASHISH', 9025, 'WORKING', 48, 67)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (4, 'AJAY', 9025, 'WORKING', 84, 56)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (5, 'AKANSHA', 9025, 'WORKING', 62, 78)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (6, 'AKSHAY', 9025, 'STUDENT', 75, 85)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (7, 'ATHARVA', 9025, 'WORKING', 45, 85)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (8, 'RAHUL', 9025, 'WORKING', 48, 67)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (9, 'VYANKATESH', 9025, 'WORKING', 84, 56)
INSERT INTO STUDENT (ROLL_NO, NAME, SECTION, CLASS, ORACLE, DEV_2000) values (10, 'RUSHIKESH', 9025, 'STUDENT', 62, 78)
```

STEP:2

```
CREATE TABLE Dev_2000_result ( ROll_NO Number (4), TOTAL Number (3), PERCENT Number (5,2), GRADE Varchar2 (10) )
```

STEP:3

```
DECLARE 
    v_student student%rowtype;
    v_result dev_2000_result%rowtype;
    grade varchar2(10);

    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT *
        FROM student;
BEGIN
    FOR v_student IN c1 LOOP 
        IF v_student.class='Working' THEN
            IF v_student.Dev_2000 <50 THEN 
                grade:='FAIL';
            ELSE grade:='PASS';
            END IF;
        ELSIF v_student.class='Student' THEN 
            IF v_student.Dev_2000 >=80 THEN grade:='HONOURS';
                elsif v_student.Dev_2000 >=60 THEN grade:='A';
                elsif v_student.Dev_2000 >=50 THEN grade:='B';
                elsif v_student.Dev_2000 >=40 THEN grade:='C';
                ELSE grade:='B';
            END IF;
        END IF; 

        INSERT INTO Dev_2000_result
        VALUES(v_student.Roll_no,
               v_student.Oracle,
               v_student.Dev_2000,
               grade);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

STEP:4

```
Execute dev_2000_result;
```

Comment: What do you mean by **print**? Print where? You code doesn't contain anything for printing.

Comment: The code prints grades in dev_2000_result table after calculating grades.Student table is taken as input.

Comment: you can look up `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. Btw, All `Grade` values inserted `NULL` into `Dev_2000_result`.

Comment: That's the problem!!! can you upload full code so the `grade values should not be null.` @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: `'Working' ` <> `'WORKING'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you compare uppercase `class` values from table with non-uppercase constants inside PL/SQL
The following code should work

```
DECLARE
    v_student student%rowtype;
    v_result dev_2000_result%rowtype;
    grade varchar2(10);
    
    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT *
    FROM STUDENT;
BEGIN
    FOR v_student IN c1 LOOP
        IF v_student.class='WORKING' THEN
            IF v_student.Dev_2000 <50 THEN grade:='FAIL'; ELSE grade:='PASS'; END IF;
        elsif v_student.class='STUDENT' THEN
            IF v_student.Dev_2000 >=80 THEN grade:='HONOURS';
            elsif v_student.Dev_2000 >=60 THEN grade:='A';
            elsif v_student.Dev_2000 >=50 THEN grade:='B';
            elsif v_student.Dev_2000 >=40 THEN grade:='C';
            ELSE grade:='B';
            END IF;
        END IF;
        
        INSERT INTO Dev_2000_result
        VALUES(v_student.Roll_no, v_student.Oracle, v_student.Dev_2000, grade);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Also, you don't need PL/SQL for this. This can be achieved using plain SQL

```
insert into dev_2000_result
select roll_no, oracle, dev_2000, decode(class,
        'WORKING', (case when dev_2000 < 50 then 'FAIL' else 'PASS' end),
        'STUDENT', (case when dev_2000 >= 80 then 'HONOURS' when dev_2000 >= 60 then 'A' when dev_2000 >= 50 then 'B' when dev_2000 >= 40 then 'C' else 'B' end)
    ) grade
from STUDENT;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7634c90c989ee0d24dc136440f793c40)